# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://alpha.processretina.com/sockjs-node?

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a PWA on React. Its working fine until now but for the last few days when i open the App url on browser(Chrome & Firefox), landing page doesn't render & blank page appears.
Following errors are shown on console:-

**Firefox:** Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://alpha.processretina.com /sockjs-node.

**Chrome:** webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'wss://alpha.processretina.com/sockjs-node' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404.

But when i hard refresh, the landing page renders.

I have tried out the solutions given under stackoverflow questions of other users but nothing has worked so far. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: it means that `wss://alpha.processretina.com/sockjs-node` is unreachable.

Comment: @demkovych So what do i do? I have tried to edit webpackHotDevClient.js but to no avail. And My SSL is managed by certboat.

Comment: the problem is on service side. Looks like they changed url or something else.

Comment: Do you mean Backend server? Then No. The server-side URL is same. I am using it as a proxy.